# Computing distribution of non-identical coin flips

Tags: computational-complexity, probability-distributions, convolution

Suppose I have $N$ coins, where coin $i$ has probability $p_i$ of coming up heads.  I flip all $N$ coins and let $S_N$ be the number of heads.  How can I compute the distribution of $S_N$ efficiently?

To be a bit more precise, we are considering the sum of $N$ independent, not-necessarily-identically distributed Bernoulli random variables; this distribution is called a [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).  Let $X_i=(x_{i,0},x_{i,1}...,x_{i,i})$ be the distribution of the sum of the first $i$ coins, where $x_{i,j}$ is the probability that the sum is $j$.  We are trying to compute $X_N$ efficiently.

It's pretty easy to compute this distribution in $O(N^2)$ time as follows.   Note that $X_1=(p_1,1-p_1)$.  Note also that $X_{i+1}$ can be computed by convolving $X_{i}$ with $(p_{i+1},1-p_{i+1})$, which takes $O(N)$ steps.  So, $X_N$ can be computed recursively in $O(N^2)$ steps.

However, we can do better.  Suppose $N=2^n$ is a power of two.  (If we not, we can pad and reduce to this case.)  We begin with $N$ distributions over $\{0,1\}$, one for each $X_i$.  We convolve these distributions in pairs to get $N/2=2^{n-1}$ distributions over $\{0,1,2\}$.  After repeating this process for $n$ steps, we will have convolved all the distributions to recover $X_n$.  Using a discrete Fourier transforms, a convolution of two length $k$ vectors can be computed in $O(k \log (k))$ steps.  Combining a binary tree structure and DFTs, I believe the overall complexity of computing $X_N$ is $O(N \log^2(N))$.

Can this be improved?  Specifically, can it be done in $O(N \log(N))$ time?

The only reference I've stumbled on for this question so far is Chen, S. X.; J. S. Liu (1997). "[Statistical Applications of the Poisson-Binomial and conditional Bernoulli distributions](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A7n44.pdf)".  I believe that that paper only mentions algorithms with complexity $O(N^2)$ or worse.